# How to determine if $f(z)=\frac{i}{z^8}$ is analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I prove that a function like $$f(z)=\dfrac{i}{z^8}$$ is analytic or not?

I have to use **Cauchy–Riemann equations** but I can't find the $u$ and $v$ functions.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, remember how complex division works:
$$
\frac{1}{w}=\frac{\overline{w}}{\lvert w\rvert ^2}.
$$
Also, recall that complex conjugates break up over multiplication: $\overline{uw}=\bar{u}\bar{w}$.

So, in all, if $z=x+iy$, then
$$
\frac{i}{z^8}=i\left(\frac{\overline{z^8}}{\lvert z^8\rvert ^2}\right)=i\left(\frac{(\bar{z})^8}{\lvert z\rvert^{16}}\right)=i\frac{(x-iy)^8}{(x^2+y^2)^8}.
$$
Now, by the Binomial Theorem,
$$
(x-iy)^8=\sum_{n=0}^{8}\binom{8}{n}x^{8-n}(-iy)^{n},
$$
from which we get
$$
\begin{align*}
\Re[(x-iy)^8]&=x^8-28x^6y^2+70x^4y^4-28x^2y^6+y^8,\\
\Im[(x-iy)^8]&=-8x^7y+56x^5y^3-56x^3y^5+8xy^7.
\end{align*}
$$
So, in all, you want to take the following for $u$ and $v$:
$$
\begin{align*}
u(x,y)&:=\Re\left[i\frac{(x-iy)^8}{(x^2+y^2)^8}\right]\\
&=-\Im\left[\frac{(x-iy)^8}{(x^2+y^2)^8}\right]\\
&=\frac{8x^7y-56x^5y^3+56x^3y^5-8xy^7}{(x^2+y^2)^8}
\end{align*}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align*}
v(x,y)&:=\Im\left[i\frac{(x-iy)^8}{(x^2+y^2)^8}\right]\\
&=\Re\left[\frac{(x-iy)^8}{(x^2+y^2)^8}\right]\\
&=\frac{x^8-28x^6y^2+70x^4y^4-28x^2y^6+y^8}{(x^2+y^2)^8}.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: OP did require the use of CR, but perhaps (one should fervently hope) a direct application wasn't intended?

Comment: @JonathanY. My sense of the question was that he specifically wanted to know how to find "$u$ and $v$".  So, that was what I answered.  If you have a different preference for answering the question, I'm sure that he could also benefit from seeing it! :-)

Comment: Yes, it seems you're right. Nevertheless, my suggestion would be to first develop a CR equivalence for $f(re^{i\theta}):=R(r,\theta)e^{i\phi(r,\theta)}$. (I'll do so tonight, unless you prefer to incorporate that into your answer.)

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. What should I do if the function was like $f(z)=1/(z-z^5)$ or $f(z)=c/(z^3+cz)$. Do I have to compute $z-z^5$ and then multiply it in its conjugate? ( It is not necessary to find $u$ and $v$ by $x,y$. As Jonathan said I can use $u$ and $v$ by $r,theta$ and then use the polar form of CR. )